# Variables globales node.js - Como hacer que una variable global no definida no de error cuando queremos comprobar si existe en la página principal

Tags: nodejs, variables-globales, ejs, express-session

Estoy intentando mostrar un contenido u otro en la página principal según exista la variable global USER o no, pero cuando cargo la página me sale directamente que la variable USER no esta definida(entonces me da el error > USER is not defined).
En PHP sería equivalente lo que quiero hacer a esto:

```
>>> $userSession = (isset($_SESSION['user']) ? $_SESSION['user'] : null);
```

Alguien sabe como hacerlo?
Declaro las variables globales así:

```
//Variables globales
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  app.locals.user = req.user;
  next();
});
```

Y el código en la plantilla EJS sería tal que así:

```
<% if(!user){ %>
        <div class="log-in" id='logIn'>
          <a href="/registry/login">Log-in</a>
          <i class="fa fa-key" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="sign-in" id='signIn'>
          <a href="/registry/signIn">Sign-in</a>
          <i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <% }else{ %>
          <div class="sign-in" id='logOut'>
            <a href="/registry/log-out">Log-out</a>
            <i class="fa fa-sign-out" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
        <% } %>
```

Gracias de ante mano !
¡ Saludos a todos !

Answer (score 0):

No se si tiene que ver porque estoy fuera y no estoy concentrado. Que te parece manejar 3 estado para la variable user.?

If (user===undefined)

If (user===null)

If (user)

Tendrías que asegurarte de pasar el valor null cuando corresponda.

Comment: Buenas Jose, gracias por tu respuesta. No era exactamente como decias pero gracias ello he probado con -typeof y me ha funcionado.
El código queda de la siguiente manera:
```
<%
          if(typeof user === 'undefined')
          {%>
        ... codigo ...
        <% }else if(user){ %>
          ... codigo ...
        <% } %>
```
Muchas gracias por contestar !!! ¡Saludos!